# Flutter List View Scrolling Only by Clicking on Edges

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm Having a List view in my app, and the problem is it does not scroll when touching the middle of the list view but only when touching the edges of the list.

[image]

and here is my View Code.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const horizontalPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10);
    final controller = Get.put(UnitsListController());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: horizontalPadding,
        child: GetX<UnitsListController>(
            builder: (controller) {
              return controller.isBusy.value
              ?const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  strokeWidth: 5,
                ),
              ): ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: controller.unitsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var item = controller.unitsList[index];

                  String address ='${item.country},${item.state},${item.area},${item.block},${item.plot},'
                      '${item.lane},${item.buildingName},${item.buildingNumber}';
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      controller.selectedUnit = item;
                      controller.onUnitTap();
                    },
                    child:  AppUnitCard(
                    type: item.type,
                    address: address,
                    rooms: item.roomsNum??0,
                    rent: item.rent,
                    bathrooms: item.bathsNum,
                    space: item.unitSpace,

                  ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Note**
that i was wrapping the Scaffold body with a SingleChildScrollView and removed it both ways it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the listview with a SingleChildScrollView and add NeverScrollableScrollPhysics to the listview

```dart
SingleChildScrollView (
 child : ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
      )
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView doesn't scroll when wrapped by Column & SingleChildScrollView on all the browsers on Android. For further details and code examples check the link:

[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80794#issuecomment-823961805](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80794)

If this link didn't help you can find more information on this link:

[All solutions for the problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80794)